# How can I display a HDMI signal plugged into my computers graphics card on my computers monitor

Tags: windows

I have a game console (PS2) connected to my computer's graphics card via SCART>SCART2HDMI and a monitor connected via HDMI on a neighbouring input on the graphics card. My question is, is it possible to view the signal from the game console on my computers monitor? Do I need some extra hardware or software to do it?

For the sake of cable management I would like to not have to plug in the game console directly into my monitor, My monitor only has one HDMI input which I wish to keep connected to my computer.

Comment: This is unclear… you have a graphics card with *inputs*?? What is it? If it has inputs there's a likelihood it could be persuaded to hairpin. 99/100 graphics cards have no input, they're pretty darn specialist, designed for video capture. I very much suspect you will have one of the 99, in which case this is not possible.

Comment: @Tetsujin Sorry I'm not sure what you're talking about, there's nothing special about my setup just a graphics card (RTX 3070) with some HDMI jacks. Do you mean that all 3 jacks are output only? I'd feel really stupid if that was the case

Comment: Graphics cards are output devices, almost exclusively. Cards with input are known generally as 'capture' cards & marketed specifically for that purpose. Randomly googled sample - https://www.pcgamer.com/best-capture-card-for-pc-gaming/ Some have passthrough.

Comment: @Tetsujin I see, well thank you, you learn something new everyday I guess. You'll have to forgive my confusion because when I googled "can I use my HDMI port for input" the top result was yes

Comment: Hmm… when I try the same search, the top hit is "Can You Convert HDMI Output to Input? No, you can't convert HDMI input to output. The internal circuitry is too different. The only alternative would be to get one of the game capture devices mentioned earlier which will allow you to receive signals." which is admittely a tad garbled, but no, 'regular' graphics cards are output only.

Comment: @Tetsujin Huh That's strange, well actually my exact search was "can I use my HDMI for input" which results in a yes answer but when I add the word port the answer changed to no. I thought Capture cards where for recording signals, I never would have guessed you needed them simply to receive but admitedly I am not at all knowllegable on the subject. I guess that's all there's to it, I'm probably going to have to hook the console directly to the monitor then. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A software/hardware solution would be to use a capture card + some application that displays it fullscreen on the monitor, e.g. [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/).

But my recommendation of a much simplier and cheaper setup would be to just buy and use any [HDMI switch](https://www.google.com/search?q=hdmi%20switch). Then you won't need to mess with cables to change what goes onto the screen.